# Programming binary tree preOrder function

Tags: c, tree, binary-tree, preorder

I'm trying to write a recursive function to print out the values in preorder. However, for some reason, it keeps printing out the same as my inOrder function. The postOrder function works fine, but I had to do the recursive function slightly differently for that one. Can you guys take a look at my code below and let me know what's wrong? I really appreciate it cuz this has been giving me trouble ALL day. Thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

typedef struct bnodestruct
{
    int value;
    struct bnodestruct *left;
    struct bnodestruct *right;
}bnode;

typedef bnode *bnodePtr;

void displayMenu();
void insert (bnodePtr *hd, int val);
void inOrder(bnodePtr hd);
void preOrder(bnodePtr hd);
void postOrder(bnodePtr hd);
void empty (bnodePtr *hd);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int val;
    bnodePtr head;
    head = NULL;    

    char option;
    int result = 0;
    while(1)
    {
    displayMenu();

    printf("Choose an option : ");
    scanf("\n%c", &option);

    /*printf("The option chosen is %c\n", option);*/

    switch (option)
    {

        case 'q':
            printf("The program is exiting...\n");
            exit(-1);
        case 'i': 
            printf("Enter an integer value to be inserted into the linked list : ");    
            scanf("%d", &val);  
            insert(&head, val);
            break;
        case 'o':
            inOrder(head);
            break;
        case 'n':
            preOrder(head);
            break;
        case 'p':
            postOrder(head);
            break;
        case 'e':
            empty(&head);
            /*inOrder (head);*/
            break;



    }

    }

}

void displayMenu()
{

    printf("\n          Menu          \n");
    printf("(q): quit the program\n");
    printf("(i): insert integer value into the binary tree\n");
    printf("(e): empty all values from the binary tree\n");
    printf("(o): list the items contained in the binary tree in order\n");
    printf("(n): list the items contained in the binary tree in pre order\n");
    printf("(p): list the items contained in the binary tree in post order\n");
}

void insert (bnodePtr *hd, int val)
{

    if (*hd == NULL)
    {
        *hd = (bnodePtr)malloc(sizeof(bnode));
        (*hd)->left = NULL;
        (*hd)->value = val;
        (*hd)->right = NULL;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (val < ((*hd)->value))
            insert (&((*hd)->left), val);
        else if (val > ((*hd)->value))
            insert (&((*hd)->right), val);
    }



}


void empty (bnodePtr *hd)
{

    bnodePtr temp1 = *hd;
    bnodePtr temp2;

    while (temp1 != NULL)
    {

        temp2 = temp1;
        temp1 = temp1->left;

        free (temp2);

    }

    *hd = NULL;

}


void inOrder (bnodePtr hd)
{

    if (hd != NULL)
    {


        inOrder(hd->left);
        printf("%d\n", hd->value);
        inOrder(hd->right);
    }



}

void preOrder (bnodePtr hd)
{

    if (hd != NULL)
    {


        printf("%d\n", hd->value);
        preOrder(hd->left);
        preOrder(hd->right);
    }


}

void postOrder (bnodePtr hd)
{

    if (hd != NULL)
    {


        inOrder(hd->left);
        inOrder(hd->right);
        printf("%d\n", hd->value);

    }



}
```

Comment: Interesting.  Looks okay to me.

Comment: You've posted *way* too much code. Your goal should be to create a *minimal* example program that demonstrates your problem -- and not just because that's polite to potential answerers. The finding/creation of such a program is also a good way to narrow down where the problem is, in case it's not where you think. (For example, your use of `scanf` to read in a single character is asking for trouble.)

Comment: ok but besides the scanf part, are u going to offer any help? the reason i posted the whole code is because there might be a mistake elsewhere in the program that someone may be able to detect to diagnose the problem i'm having with the preOrder function. and also, now i also think my postOrder function is messed up as well

Comment: Just for the record, I get different output from `preOrder` and `inOrder`. Of course, both would print the same for some degenerate trees. Are you perhaps inserting values in ascending order? That would produce such a degenerate tree.

Answer (score 3):

```
void postOrder (bnodePtr hd)
{
    if (hd != NULL)
    {
        inOrder(hd->left);  // XXX
        inOrder(hd->right); // XXX
        printf("%d\n", hd->value);
    }
}
```

That's your problem right there. You're calling `inOrder` where you should be calling `postOrder`.

Comment: naw thats actually not the problem though, well actually I'm not sure. cuz I originally tried doing it as you said, by recursively calling postOrder in the postOrder function, but for some reason, it would not work. it just prints out the list in descending order. so i searched online and what one code said to do was to call the function you use to print the list 'in order' in your postOrder function. my postOrder function prints out, but I dont think it might be right either.

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Comment: i was just saying that the only reaason i called inOrder in the postOrder function is becasue for some reason, when I attempted to recursively call postOrder in the postOrder function, nothing happened. but after looking online, i saw somebody call inOrder in their postOrder function. even though i dont think it's right, the program at least prints out something. recursively calling postOrder did absolutely nothing with me.